# Strange character appearing after doing UTF-8 Base64 Encoding/Decoding Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, encoding, utf-8

I ran some input text through this online converter UTF8

https://www.base64encode.org/

I threw the output into my API, which decodes it and does some further processing.

## API Call

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/highlight", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String highlightTester(@RequestBody String programInput) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] decoded = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(programInput);
    String result = new String(decoded, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

As I log this information, I keep getting a weird character..

## Input

```
{
    "code": "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"
}
```

## Strange Output

```
....#1e0010">�</span><span style="color: #f92672">^</span>....
```

Now, this happens with literally every single type of input I pass in, even if I use a different encoder. Why is this happening?

## More Ouput

```
r�^wefwefwef
```

I'm using **Java Spring Boot** to run my API, so wondering if me passing this through Postman is adding some additional flavor to my call.

Comment: Give us a proper example that we can reproduce the issue. Which input you give, which input you receive in controller etc.

Comment: You need to specify the character set when you create the String. **Never** use the single argument `new String(byte[])` in a server application, always use the two argument version where you specify the character set as the second argument: `new String(decoded, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`

Comment: The mime decoder also feels like a strange choice. Have you tried with `Base64.getDecoder()`?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Updated. Also, I have tried the getDecoder with no change.

Comment: Hold on. You're running the entire JSON fragment through the decoder? Or just the base64 string?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen ok, that made me realize the key in my post is definitely wrong.. dumb mistake. I'm not intentionally passing in the entire fragment, does Spring parse out my value?

Comment: No, why would it? You're passing it the entire request body. Do you need the JSON cruft? Can't you just post the base64 string?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen For some reason I was thinking it would bind the name and pull out the key for me. . I've fixed my entire issue, thanks for waking me up. If you post as a solution Ill accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the entire request body to the base64 decoder. Since the request body not only contains the base64-encoded string but also JSON markup, decoding will either fail or result in unexpected output.

To fix, either:

- make sure that you only have base64 content in your request body; or
- parse the JSON in your request body and extract the base64 string that you want to decode; or
- create a bean corresponding to your JSON structure and let Spring map the request body to that bean automatically.